# CSS, div border displaying as double

Tags: css

I'm not great with CSS, but i'm lost as to what is happening here...
can anyone shed some light? i was after just the **one** div box

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    html,
    #presenter{
      position: fixed;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      border-style: dashed;
      border-color: red;
   }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id='presenter'>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: It's not the double border. you are giving border to the html and div together. Rather give a separate css for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are adding a border to the `html` tag as well. Remove it's reference from the css and it will work : http://jsfiddle.net/Eta8G/

```
#presenter{
      position: fixed;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      border-style: dashed;
      border-color: red;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the `html,` part in your css. Drop that.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    #presenter{
      position: fixed;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      border-style: dashed;
      border-color: red;
   }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id='presenter'>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is because you are applying style on entire html document as well as the on div container.

```
html, #presenter {
      position: fixed;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      border-style: dashed;
      border-color: red;
   }
```

so one border of html document and one of your div.

You just need to use `#presenter` not `html`

```
#presenter {
  //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have applied the border for HTML also. So that you are getting two borders. Remove html from the style.

```
 <html>
<head>
<style>
  #presenter{
  position: fixed;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='presenter'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `html` from css

```
    #presenter{
      position: fixed;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      border-style: dashed;
      border-color: red;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving styles to html as well

```
   html, #presenter{
      position: fixed;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      border-style: dashed;
      border-color: red;
   }
```

change to

```
    #presenter{
      position: fixed;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      border-style: dashed;
      border-color: red;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove html from the css.

```
#presenter {
  position: fixed;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: red;
}
```